# How to enable expiry date for passwords in pass?

Tags: password, password-store

I am using the linux password manager called "pass". Is there a way to set an expiry date on the stored passwords?

I couldn't find any info on google or pass' man page. Do I have to resort to using another password manager to do this? 
I do use keepass for my smart phone (that's why I noticed a couple of my passwords expired). However, I prefer pass' cli for my desktop pc and I don't carry around all my passwords on my phone.

Comment: Why not just use `chage`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Could you elaborate? Is chage applicable for instance for my stackoverflow password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pass` password manager is, by its own manual's admission, a simple wrapper around GnuPG and Git, and does not support expiration dates on passwords.

I would possibly suggest editing the password and adding that information to the password entry's text.  This would obviously break scripts that relied on `pass` for extracting passwords (and that expects the password to be the *only* thing stored).

Comment: That's what I also have thought about. Fortunately I don't have any scripts using pass.

Comment: @Torsten That's what I do, along with any other information about the account that I want to protect (like password creation date and possibly a short descriptive text).

Comment: It should be noted that if any script is parsing the output of `pass`, they should definitely only be using the first line. There are many reasons for users to put additional text in the file, such as TOTP URIs, security questions, etc.